# Aligning some multiline equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I want to align these set of equations such that all the equality symbols are all under each other. I try to use `align` environment as I state below. But I want to see if we can make these lines shorter in order to get the same result.

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}‎
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{align*}
  ‎|E(‎\mathcal{C}-x)|-‎‎|E(‎\mathcal{C}^x)| &=‎ ‎(n-1)‎\Phi‎_{d-1}(n-2)-(n-1) 
  ‎\Phi‎_{d-2}(n-2)\\‎
  &=‎ 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  (n-1)‎{{n-2}\choose{d-1}}‎‎
  \end{aligned}‎‎
  \\
  &= ‎
  \begin{aligned}[t]‎
  d‎{{d}\choose{n-1}} ‎ 
  \end{aligned}
  \end{align*}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following code short enough? No `aligned` environments, no loading of unneeded packages, use of the amsmath-based `\binom` macro instead of the Plain-TeX `\choose` directive (which uses infix notation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  ‎|E(‎\mathcal{C}-x)|-‎‎|E(‎\mathcal{C}^x)| 
  &=‎ ‎(n-1)‎\Phi‎_{d-1}(n-2) - (n-1)\Phi‎_{d-2}(n-2)\\‎
  &=‎ (n-1)\binom{n-2}{d-1} \\
  &= ‎d‎\binom{d}{n-1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```